Solve $x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=z$
I'm working on this:

Solve the differential equation $x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=z$, given in the entire $xy$-plane.

From the equations $\frac{dx}{dt}=x$, $\frac{dy}{dt}=y$, $\frac{dz}{dt}=z$ I found that $x=c_1e^t$ , $y=c_2e^t$ , $z=c_3e^t$, then I tried to solve the homogeneous equation $x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=0$:
$$x=c_1e^t \;,\; y=c_2e^t \Rightarrow\frac{x}{y}=\text{constant} \Rightarrow z(x,y)=\frac{x}{y} \text{ is a solution for hom. eq. }$$
but then I realized that this isn't defined on every point of the $xy$-plane (same problem using $\frac{y}{x}$). How can I find a solution that works on the entire plane?
On top of that I'm not sure on how to find a solution for the non-homogeneous case to add to the previous one. The solution $z=ax+by$ is easy to see but I dont know how to get here from $z=c_3e^t$. It's enough to say that $e^t=\frac{x}{c_1}=\frac{y}{c_2}=\frac{z}{c_3}$ so $z=ax$ and $z=by$ must be solutions?
Can you please help me?

The general solution of $x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=z$ is : $$z(x,y)=xF\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$ $F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined if some boundary condition is specified). The function $z=ax+by$ is a particular case of linear function $F(X)=a+bX$. With other kind of functions $F$ you can obtain infinity many solutions of the PDE.

The $C^1$ function $z(x,y)$ defined on the punctured plane $U = \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ satisfies the equation $$x \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = z$$ for all $(x,y) \in U$ if and only if $z(tx,ty) = tz(x,y)$ for all $t > 0$ and $(x,y) \in U$.
Indeed, assume that $z(tx,ty) = tz(x,y)$ for all $t, (x,y)$. Then, differentiation by $t$ implies exactly the PDE above. Now assume that the PDE holds. Fix $(x,y) \in U$ and consider $a(t) = z(tx, ty)$. Clearly, $$\frac{da}{dt}(t) = x \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}(tx,ty) + y \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}(tx,ty) = \frac{1}{t}z(tx,ty) = \frac{1}{t}a(t).$$ Solving for $a$ the equation $a' = a/t$ gives $a = Ct$ with an integration constant $C = a(1)$. This implies $z(tx, ty) = tz(x,y)$.
Clearly, this criterion extends to functions on the whole plane by continuity. I.e. a $C^1$ function $z$ defined on $\mathbb R^2$ is the solution to the equation above if and only if $z(tx,ty) = tz(x,y)$ for all $t > 0$ and all $(x,y)$.
Edit The conditions on the global solution actually imply that $z(x,y) = ax + by$, i.e. $z$ is linear. This can be easily seen by observing that if $z$ satisfies the PDE and has zero gradient at $(x,y)=(0,0)$, then $z = 0$ everywhere.

Where is the solution $z(x,y)=x\cdot f(\frac{y}{x})$ ?

@gpmath I think the question asks for the solution defined and sufficiently smooth everywhere on the plane (including zero).
